# Rails app making ajax calls to localhost when published on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I´ve developed an Rails app which works fine when running on localhost.

However, when pushing it to Heroku I run into problems with my ajax calls, which can look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/getTemplatesForCategory/"+categoryId,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            this.setState({templates: data, suppliers: []});
        }.bind(this)
    });
```

This is routed like this in my routes.rb:

```
  get 'getTemplatesForCategory/:categoryId', to: 'templates#getTemplatesForCategory'
```

When these run on the Herou-version the console gives me this error:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myappname.herokuapp.com/templates/8' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:3000/getTemplatesForCategory/7'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

I´m using a Procfile which seems to work but I can't really figure out why the calls go to my localhost?

Comment: Try to access your heroku app over `http` most likely it will work. More on mixed content error - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Security/MixedContent

Comment: If you want to use your app over `https` setting `force_ssl` in `production.rb` might solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered it was an completely different issue that caused this. Heroku did not pick up the changes to my javascript code so it was actually the old code make request to the localhost address.